# Specifying a JDBC Database Driver Max Threads

Tags: coldfusion, datasource

I have a ColdFusion 10 server. I am using a JDBC driver to connect to a db2 database. I came across this note. Where is this setting? I also looked at neo*.xml files, but I did not see any db driver thread setting. I am not sure if this is specific to ColdFusion 2016 either. I also looked for it in ColdFusion 2018 administrator with no luck.

> ColdFusion Server takes the SQL content of the cfquery tag and passes
>   it to the specified driver for the data source. The driver request is
>   handled by a thread. By default, the ColdFusion Administrator is
>   configured to limit the amount of active threads to 5.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/database-connections-handled-coldfusion.html

[image]

Comment: It is in the datasource's settings, isn't it?

Comment: @JamesAMohler  I added a screenshot of various properties. Please see above.

Comment: @JamesAMohler Can you please go back and add data source again . Use IP for remote server and localhost for local server for Server .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColdFusion administrator limits the max connections to 5 and it will be affected only if you disable the "maintain connections".

If you want to increase the default active connections to 100, please enable "maintain connections" and check the "limit connections" to some number.

ColdFusion, by default, will not set the default max connection property on neo-datasource.xml.
Please find the below XML configurations for the 2 configurations.

```
<var name="myDataSource">
    ....
    <var name="pooling">
        <boolean value="true" />
    </var>
    ....
    <struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
        <var name="MAXCONNECTIONS">
            <string>100</string>
        </var>
    </struct>
    ....
</var>
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks.

Comment: On a separate question, is it possible to force these connections run in parallel. I am trying to resolve some time out problems. Of course, I will look into the queries to see what kind of bottlenecks exist. Just curious.